# Why TypeScript does not throw compilation error for incompatible method signature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm very new on the TS/React stack and I created a very simple component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface ButtonProps {
    counter: number;
    setCounter: (increment: number)=>void;
    increment: number;
}

export function Button(props:ButtonProps) {
      const clickEvent = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        props.setCounter(props.increment);
    };

    return <button onClick={clickEvent}>{props.increment}</button>;
}
```

and then when I tried to use it I was surprised to see that this code compiles:

```js
import React,  { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { Display } from './Display';

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5);

  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Button counter={counter} setCounter={incrementCounter} increment={1}></Button>
     <Button counter={counter} setCounter={incrementCounter} increment={5}></Button>
     <Button counter={counter} setCounter={incrementCounter} increment={10}></Button>
     <Display message={counter} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting to have an error on the const incrementerCount line because the method does not respect the signature on the ButtonProps interface -> setCounter: (increment: number)=>void;

Could you explain to me why this code compiles?

Regards

Comment: That _does_ respect the signature. It'll accept a number parameter, it just ignores it.

Comment: See [the documentation for comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).  Someone could write this up as an answer but it's very likely that there's an existing question.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting TS to be more strict and now I understand thanks to the documentation link why it is not.